# Slack Block Kit Plain-Text input element update text value

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

Im currently writing a small Slack App in Python using Bolt. Im creating a Modal in response to a slash command which consists of a few Plain-Text input fields and two date pickers.

On one of the [text input fields](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#input) i set `dispatch_action` to `True` and define `on_character_entered` as trigger action as suggested by the API reference.
This way i can handle the event issued when the user enters text into the field.

This does work great and i push a new modal view when a specific keyword is entered. I store the initial's modal view id and hash to access it again when the newly pushed modal view is submitted in order to call `views_update()` on it ([api](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#updating-pushing-views)). The idea is to change parts of the text based on the input of the second modal view.

This seems to work, but does not quite do what i want. The Plain-Text input does not have a field for its value, only for `initial_value` (which is the only thing i change in the `views_update()`).
When i return to the first modal view which contains the text input it still displays the original text without reflecting the changes, but from the response of the `views_update()` call i can see that the `initial_value` was changed correctly.

I *guess* that the `initial_value` only sets the text when the view is created for the first time, but does this mean there is no way to update a text input's text value without recreating the whole view?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i just found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759612/when-does-a-block-id-need-to-be-updated). Basically you need to force slack to rebuild the ui element (in this case the text input field) by giving it a new block id when calling `views_update()`.

Then the initial value gets used to fill the text input thus solving my issue.